# Css Styling difference in Firefox 22.0 -- IE10

Tags: css

The following code has styling issue. It works well in IE10 but not in mozilla firefox version 22.0 does not support width of 20px. How could it be standardized for both browsers?

```
html{

    font: 10pt 'Segoe UI';
    color: #505050;
    -moz-outline:none;
    outline:none;
  }



     #ta{
      width: 20px;
      height: 385px;
      float: left;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 0 0 0 1px;
      border: none;
      background: transparent;color: #2e2e2e;

      font-family: 'Courier New';
      font-weight: 100;
      font-size: 20px;
      letter-spacing: 3px;

      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
       user-select: none;
      -khtml-user-select: none;
    }
```

Comment: Can you put some HTML markup as well will be helpful to debug

Comment: - this will work in Firefox - so there must be an other bug

Comment: it does not support 20px  for width,  I have tested it with page inspector in mozilla.

Comment: @user2284968 it does support it. Is there any overwriting with the classes?. When you post the HTML it would be easier to help you. You could create a Demo at http://www.fiddle.net :)

Comment: But it is out of allignment, if the same code is run on IE it produces a neat output but in mozilla it produces something a little bit out of order..and thank you for suggesting fiddle.net :)

Comment: I'm really sorry the Firefox version is 27..